# Alt Codes not navigating out of User Control

Tags: vb.net, winforms

In our application's main processing form, we utilise alt codes (Having &Label as the label text to quickly navigate to a control using Alt-L, for example) for quick navigation to hop around the screen if the user needs to move out of the traditional navigation flow - but recently we have hit a snag:

We have a user control which handles quite a bit on the form, which has a control within it that needs to share an alt-code (Alt-R), with another control outside of the user control. Normally, this wouldn't be an issue, since we could just set them both to Alt-R, and Alt-R would toggle between the two. Since one of the controls is inside the user control, and one is not, however, once the focus is within the user control, it won't toggle outside of the user control with two controls sharing an Alt code.

Is there any property I can set to allow this without writing custom logic to handle? The main issue with custom logic is that some of these alt-codes can be user defined, and it wouldn't be ideal to have to write an all-encompassing handling method when I imagine this should *just work* within the normal Windows Forms Engine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find a different solution than using P/Invoke for this.
If it doesn't fit in the scheme, there might be an alternate trivial way.

First problem: intercept a KeyDown event.
The KeyDown event handler is not that useful in this case, so you have to go "under" and get the WindowProc message.
Second problem: let the Container control know that a KeyDown event has to be processed. Couldn't find any good solution other than using PostMessage.

Declare the dll import:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function PostMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function
```

Then override the ProcessCmdKey of the UserControl:

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
  'If ALT has been pressed...
  If (keyData And Keys.Alt) > 0 Then
     '... if another key is pressed aswell...
     If (keyData Xor Keys.Alt) > 64 Then
        '...pass the information to the container to see if it is interested
        PostMessage(Me.ParentForm.Handle, CType(msg.Msg, UInt32), msg.WParam, msg.LParam)
        Return True
     End If
  End If
  'Not a key we are interested in
  Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

If you can't/won't P/Invoke, you might obtain a similar effect setting the focus to a random control in the parent container.
So, substitute PostMessage with:

```
Me.ParentForm.Controls(0).Focus()
```

But this, of course, will move the focus for any ALT/key combination.